# Shopping Basket - add items to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I have a csv file which contains items scraped from a supermarket website. I have now displayed them on html and added a "Add to cart" button. I want the item name and price to be saved on to local storage when the button is pressed.

The idea is to then show these saved data in the basket.

Showing my existing code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--<link href ="styles.css" type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>


 <body>

<!--     Header-->
     <div id="header"> 
      <button type="button" class="button">Basket</button>
     </div>

<!--     CSV FILE DATA WILL APPEAR HERE-->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div id="order_list" onload="appendRow()"><p id="tableintro"> Choose your desired supermarket</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>    

<!--THIS BUTTON WILL LOAD DATA FROM CSV FILE-->
<div id="sidebar">

     <div align="center">
<button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_sainsburys" class="btn btn-info">Sainsburys Colindale</button>
    </div>
  </div>

//Save item to local storage - DOESNT SEEM TO WORK
   <script>
       function SaveItem() {
      var usrObject = {};
        usrObject.product = document.getElementsById("12at").value;
        usrObject.price = document.getElementById("34at").value;


        //Store User

        localStorage[usrObject.product] = JSON.stringify(usrObject);    
}
     </script>
```

Below is the code i am using to retrieve data from my CSV file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_sainsburys').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"sainsburys.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var tesco_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
   for (var count = 0; count < tesco_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = tesco_data[count].split(",");
     var name = cell_data[0];
     var price = cell_data[1];

      if (count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<tr><th>' + name + '</th><th>' + price + '</th><th>action</th></tr>';
       continue;
      }

      table_data += '<tr><td id="12at">' + name + '</td><td id="34at">' + price + '</td><td><button type="button onclick="SaveItem()">Add to cart</button></td></tr>';
   }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#order_list').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you duplicating ids 12at and 34at on every row? That won't work. You're also not specifically looking for the name and price from the row that was clicked. You'll need to take the DOM element for the button, navigate up to the parent tr and then look for the tds that are children of that tr to find the row you've clicked. You probably want to use classes to distinguish the tds beneath it, not IDs, as you're not supposed to duplicate IDs on the page.

Comment: Hi, I am still not quite sure how i can do this? Can you elaborate?